# Find and Echo only the date (with format) in String Output on Bash

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, find, datetime-format

I am trying to get the `date "+%a %b %d %R:%S %Y"` in bash.

here's the sample command and output

`$ xscreensaver-command --time
XScreenSaver 5.32: screen non-blanked since Thu Oct 29 12:15:05 2015 (hacks: #184, #60)`

I am trying to get the the value `Thu Oct 29 12:15:05 2015` on the string.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9,$10}'`

Comment: If AvinashRaj's code does not answer your question, you really need to explain better what you are asking.

Comment: this also works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append with GNU grep:

```
2>&1 | grep -Po 'since \K.*(?= \()'
```

Output:

```
Thu Oct 29 12:15:05 2015
```